# A single or multiple gopaths for multiple projects using godep

Tags: go

Currently I'm using godep for package vendoring for Go. The problem is that I'm working on multiple projects depending on different versions of a certain package. I can't decide how to structure my GOPATH(s). I have several options:

- Use a single GOPATH and use godep restore when switching between projects. The different versions of the certain package will be switched.
- Use a GOPATH per project and only use godep restore when needed.

Which option is recommended and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm working on multiple projects depending on different versions of a certain package

Then I would recommend a `GOPATH` per project, in order to better isolate each dependencies, and make sure there isn't any mix_up in said dependencies.

Within each `GOPATH`, you still can use the dependency manager of your choice.

I use that even with vendoring (just to be sure to get an independent workspace)

For vendoring, (Go 1.5+), I use **[govendor](https://github.com/kardianos/govendor)**, typically:

```
govendor fetch +m
```

> Pull in new dependencies or update existing dependencies directly from remotes with `govendor fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, this has been obsolete since 1.5 and the advent of vendoring in Go.